# (JPQL) - Query for getting user with highest number of records

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jpql

Excuse me for anking again about this issue but I need to have a JPA query for this:

```
select username, count(*)
from Records
group by username
order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```

I thought about smth like:

```
select r.username,count(*) from Records r order by r.username desc
```

and then to call

```
getResultList().get(0)
```

but I am allowed to write only:

```
select r from Records r order by r.username desc
```

and in this case I do not know how to get what I need.
Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL query has a group by, and orders by count. The JPA query doesn't have any group by and orders by user name. So I don't see how they could return the same thing.

The equivalent JPQL query is

```
select r.username, count(r.id)
from Record r
group by r.username
order by count(r.id) desc
```

If you call `setMaxResults(1)` on the Query object, the limit clause will be added to the generated SQL query, making it completely equivalent.